# $ f'(x)+g'(y)=h(x)+t(y)$

Tags: functions

$f$ and $h$ are two functions of $x$

$g$ and $t$ are two functions of $y$

And $f'$ derivative of $f$ ,$g'$ derivative of $g$

Is it correct to say that by identification $f'(x)=h(x)$ and $g'(y)=t(y)$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there may be a constant. For example :

$$f'(x)=x^2+1$$
$$g'(y)=y^2+3$$
$$h(x)=x^2$$
$$t(y)=y^2+4$$

:)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. Since we have
$$
f'(x) - h(x) = t(y) - g'(y),
$$
we know that each side must be a constant. If you're not convinced, consider what happens if we change $y$ but not $x$. However, this constant need not be zero. The best we can conclude is
$$
f'(x) = h(x) + C\;\;\;\;;\;\;\;\; g'(y) = t(y) - C
$$
for some constant $C$.

This constant $C$ is very important and definitely can't be neglected. For example, in the hydrogen atom problem in quantum mechanics, these constants appear as the quantum numbers of electron states.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. If you isolate the x-terms on one side and the y-terms on the other, you get
$$f'(x)-h(x)=t(y)-g'(y)$$
Since the LHS depends only on $x$ and the RHS depends only on $y$, you may conclude that both sides are equal to some constant $C$.

So you have $$f'(x)=h(x) + C$$ and $$g'(y) = t(y)-C$$
where the $C$ is the same in both equations.

Note there may be many values of $C$ for which this is true, or there may be none. Not every value of $C$ necessarily produces equations which have solutions (but they may).